# How to use NextJS SSR for page with useEffect asynchronous initialization?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a NextJS app that I'd like to use SSR for to render blog like pages as fast as possible, specifically caching them at the edge.

The problem I'm facing is that the pages are rendered using a library that initializes them asynchronously in a `useEffect` `setTimeout`.

Is there any way to build these pages on the server and cache the result at the edge for subsequent requests? The data fetching/caching part isn't an issue.

[Here's an example Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/heuristic-forest-vc8dvl?file=%2Fapp%2FContent.tsx) illustrating the problem. You'll see the SSR content shows `false` for the variable and flashes noticeably on the client before switching to `true`.

`Content.tsx` is a super simple example component that initializes asynchronously. In my app, this is a 3rd party library that I dont have control over.

```js
export const Content = () => {
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setReady(true));
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1 className={isReady ? styles.ready : styles["not-ready"]}>
      Content component ready: <br /> {JSON.stringify(isReady)}
    </h1>
  );
};
```

Note: This CSB uses NextJS 13's `app` directory but the problem exists in Next12 with `pages` as well.

The closest solution I've come across so far is this [useSSE library](https://github.com/kmoskwiak/useSSE), but it feels hacky and also requires me to opt out of Vercel deployed server handling.

Comment: By design, a `useEffect` only runs on the client. Without a working example, this is speculative: You mention it's loading your data async, which could mean it's making a request to some API to retrieve that data. Use dev tools, open the network tab, and look for outgoing requests. From there, it may be as simple as fetching data from that API via `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. Then, all incoming requests would be intercepted by your edge function which attaches a `stale-while-revalidate` header on the response. We do something like this for retrieving data from our CMSs.

Comment: Again, the above is speculative. I've never had to deal with a 3rd party library that only initializes a page with data within a useEffect. That seems counter-intuitive for SEO unless the authors never intended the page to be SSR'd. On that note, a better [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a stripped down example using this 3rd party library within NextJS.

Comment: I noted that that data fetching part _isnt_ an issue. I can do that with `getServerSideProps`. The issue is that the underlying React library initializes its instance asynchronously. The transformed data (which is needed to render the React components) is not ready until a `setTimeout` inside a `useEffect`

Comment: Ah, in that case, since the library can only be initialized on the client, then I don’t see how it can be cached on the edge — I’m assuming it’s doing some sort of DOM manipulations/calculations/drawing which is why it’s being initialized in a useEffect. That said, I’m still not understanding why it’s using a setTimeout. That aside, from a performance stand point, even if you could load and cache it on the sever, this library sounds heavy enough that when it gets hydrated on the client, it could be quite resource heavy and result in a slow TTI.

Comment: Good hunch. The library is a browser editing framework called [ProseMirror](https://prosemirror.net/) wrapped in a React rendering framework called [TipTap](https://tiptap.dev/). I believe the DOM initialization can be done in a JSDom context, but I have no way to make it happen synchronously.

Comment: I've been thinking about this challenge and I think this *might* work for you: Build a façade of this rich text component using plain HTML derived from the dynamic data on the server-side. This façade is completely static up until a user interacts with it on the client (on mouse over, on click, etc). Once interacted with, swap out the static component for the interactive one. You should be able to cache the page while also retaining the interactivity on the client.

Comment: So I considered an approach like that, but in order to create the HTML markup, I need the React components that render them, and in order to render the React components, I need an instance of the ProseMirror editor, and to do that, were back where we started.